# Gnome Shell ignores (mouse-based) copy-paste commands

Tags: gnome-shell, clipboard, copy-and-paste

I have an issue with a PC with two monitors running Ubuntu 19.10 and GNOME Shell 3.34.1. I often do copy-paste texts between the two monitors, e.g. from a notebook that is open on one monitor into a command terminal that is open on the other. I usually select `Copy` and `Paste` commands from context menus using the mouse.

What happens since one of the recent package upgrades is that the system ignores "most" such operations. I.e. a copy may be silently ignored and hence the next paste will insert a the content of the clipboard. Obviously this can have nasty effects when pasting into a command terminal.

Hovering with the mouse for, say, a second before right-clicking (to bring up the context menu) and then before left-clicking in the context menu (to select the command) apparently brings some relief, but the behavior is still ill predictable and the system barely usable in the intended mode.

How can I diagnose the root cause of this problem and solve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Performing copy twice (either by keyboard or mouse) in rapid succession seems to do the trick. Disappointing, though.